# sql sorting column with both number and text

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting

I'm trying to arrange a column with values like:

```
1 test
amazon
11 basic
2 hi
02toad
ikea
22
burger 
002 paper
```

I want them to be arranged like this:

```
1 test
2 hi
002 paper
02toad
11 basic
22
amazon
burger 
ikea
```

So i what i want is to first sort on number and then on the text. Not all values do contains numbers and not all contains text.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Some of them have support for numeric sensitive collations!

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is tricky in SQL Server, but you can do it:

```
order by try_convert(bigint, left(col, patindex('%[^0-9]%', col + 'x'))),
         col
```

You need to convert the leading digits to a number for this to work, because your ordering treats the initial digits as a number.

That actually puts the letters before the numbers.  This is easily remedied with another key:

```
order by (case when col like '[0-9]%' then 1 else 2 end),
         try_convert(bigint, left(col, patindex('%[^0-9]%', col + 'x'))),
         col
```

In general, if you are trying to interpret a number at the beginning of the string *as a number*, then you probably want the value in a different column.  In other words, you might consider fixing your data model as well.